# make entire row clickable for checkbox feature without deactivating the checkbox itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

I have a template like:

```
    {% if websites %}
        <h3>Delete websites:</h3>
        <div class="row">
            {% for website in websites %}
                <div class="row checkbox">
                    <h4>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{ website.name }}:
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                        {{ website.url}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete_website" value="{{ website.id}}">
                    </div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    {% endif %}

    ...

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $('.checkbox').click(function(){
        ($(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked")));
   });

</script>
```

It creates

[image]

where the row should be clickable, so anywhere from "webapi" to the checkbox clicking should check or uncheck the checkbox. As is, the jquery func works on the name (webapi) and the url (http://...)  and whitespace between the 3 pieces, but deactivates clicking the checkbox, probably because it doubles the action (clicking it checks it, so my func unchecks it). I change to:

```
        <h3>Delete websites:</h3>
        <div class="row">
            {% for website in websites %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <h4>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        {{ website.name }}:
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                            {{ website.url}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete_website" value="{{ website.id}}">
                    </div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    {% endif %}

    ...

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $('.checkbox').click(function(){
        ($(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked")));
   });

</script>
```

this time only wrapping the first 2 elements in the row as ".checkbox", and now clicking the checkbox works again...but clicking the rest of the row doesn't change the checkbox (probably because the `.find(':checkbox')` no longer works). How can I wrap this row to be clickable without deactivating clicking the checkbox itself? I implemented this in HTML for a different task and it didn't work on clicking whitespace which I don't like one bit. My main goal is to fix the JS below to not double check the box when you click on the box itself, so user can click anywhere in the row to check the box, but still copy/paste any text in the row. Thank you

```js
    $('.checkbox').click(function(){
        ($(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked")));
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row checkbox">
                    <h4>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    webapi:
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                        http://127.0.0.1:8001/status/
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete_website" value="2">
                    </div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
```

Comment: Too bad you shot that answer by mgilson. Labels are a good build-in feature to make a larger area clickable. Formally your current mark-up cannot be enclosed in a label, because it contains block elements (h4 and div), but you may be able to change the mark-up a little. And if you specify the `for` attribute, the entire label will be clickable for the checkbox.

Comment: he deleted it, but I don't wanna remove all the divs as they allow the bootstrap `col-md-#` spacing

Comment: labels are a good solution, but in my experience, they don't make the whitespace clickable which makes them essentially useless. I think the entire row should be clickable or not at all

Comment: If you link them to the checkbox correctly, the whole area of the label is clickable. That does mean you have to give the checkboxes unique ids. You could even consider using some positioning tricks to overlay the label over the row if you don't want to mess too much with the existing mark-up. I know it's probably not going to be your final solution, but to clarify things, I've put an example in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Given the application, a JavaScript solution is fine too. But just to show how you could position a label over the entire row and link it to the checkbox, I've made the example below.

There is a disadvantage, though: because the label is an overlay for the row, it blocks mouse access to the other row elements. This would make it hard for users to select pieces of text from the row.

```css
.row {
  position: relative; 
}

label.overlay {
  /* Position inside the nearest positioned element, in this case the row. */
  position: absolute;
  /* Make it fill that parent element. */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* Some shade, just to show the area in this demo */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="row checkbox">
  <h4>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      webapi:
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
      http://127.0.0.1:8001/status/
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete_website" value="2" id="cb_delete_website_2">
      <label class="overlay" for="cb_delete_website_2"></label>
    </div>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: you're in the lead. it is annoying to not be able to copy, but my main goal in this pattern is just making clickable rows for lists of items to keep or delete. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to correct your markup. As per [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) "*Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows*.
"
So your markup should be like :

```
<div class="row checkbox">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="clickable">
                webapi:
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="clickable">
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/status/
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" class="the-checkbox" name="delete_website" value="2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Next,
you can assign a class eg. clickable to all the elements on which you want to bind click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".clickable").on("click",function(){
            var theCheckBox=$(this).closest(".checkbox").find(".the-checkbox");
            theCheckBox.prop("checked",!theCheckBox.prop("checked"));

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark every line with `lineClass` or whatever selector you choose, and:

```
$('.lineClass').each((i,line) => { //Click checkbox when line is clicked
           const $checkbox = $(line).find('input[type=checkbox]');
           $checkbox.click(e=> e.stopPropagation());
           $(line).click(()=>$checkbox.click());
  })
```